# Jquery: Toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML page structure like this:

```
<div class="editable>CONTENT
    <span class="multiple-users">span-content</span>
    <span class="multiple-users">span-content2</span>
    <span class="multiple-users">span-content3</span>
</span>
```

When I click on a span element with class "multiple-users", I want it to replace everything in the div of class "editable" with the content of the clicked span. And when I click on the content of the clicked span, I want it to revert back to its original form, replacing it with everything that was originally in the div.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('span.multiple-users').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).text().match(/[0-9]+/);
        var old_html = $(this).closest('div.editable').html();
        var instructor_obj = $(this).closest('div.editable');

        instructor_obj.html("<span id=" + id + " >Instructor ID: " + id + "</span>");

        $('#' + id).click(function () {
            $(this).closest('div.editable').html(old_html);
        });    
    });
});
```

But this doesn't do exactly what I want it to do. When I click on a span of class="multiple-users," it replaces everything in the div with the span-content, and when I click on the span-content, it reverts back to the original contents. However, when I try to click on the span again, it doesn't replace everything in the div with the content of the span clicked on.

In short, it doesn't toggle properly. Can you see what's wrong with my code?

Comment: so an event handler inside an event handler isn't working for you ?

Comment: Are you saying that I can't have an event handler inside an event handler?

Comment: I'm saying you shouldn't, as everytime you click the span, a new event handler will be bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to **delegate the event**, as you are dynamically **creating new elements**. When you click the span element the events are bound to the old elements which were destroyed but not to the **new ones.**

```
$('.editable').on('click', 'span.multiple-users', function () {
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/BKFN3/16/)**

Answer (score 0):

it should really be separated in to two:

```
<div class="editable">
  <div class="ed-area">
    old content
  </div>
  <div class="control">
    <span>Content One</span>
    <span>Content Two</span>
    <span>Content Three</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  var control = $("div").find(".control");
  var oldText = $(".editable").html();
  $.each(control, function(){
    var that = $(this);
    var newText = that.html();
    that.on({
      click:function(){
        var className = that.attr("class");
        if(className){
          fillin = oldText;
        } else {
          fillin = newText;
        }
        that.classToggle("selected");
        $(".editable").html(fillin);
      }
    });
  });
});
```